# Can't show the parsed data in Listview using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I want to show the data in listview using array adapter. After hitting the service and parsing the data, I can't show it in Litview. Works good in Textview but not in Listview.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView tvData;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    tvData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONTask().execute("http://a.nextput.com/offers/19/o/a0f252064bd27339607c7166d270d82a/f?aff_id=56556_18&im=25");
        }

    });


}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("offers");

            StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();
            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String contactid = finalObject.getString("app_name");
                //String custname = finalObject.getString("name");
                //String custemail = finalObject.getString("email");
                //String custgender = finalObject.getString("gender");
                //String mobileno = finalObject.getString("mobile");

                finalBufferData.append(contactid + " - ");
            }
            return finalBufferData.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader !=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // tvData.setText(result);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        tvData.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `result` variable is a single String, not a list. You have to use a an array/Arraylist for an ArrayAdapter

Comment: @cricket_007 How and where to use Arraylist in this class. Please help.

Comment: I think you need to clear your concepts about ListView. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

you should use an arraylist instead of a string to put all your contactid as shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView tvData;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Button btnHit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
tvData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new JSONTask().execute("http://a.nextput.com/offers/19/o/a0f252064bd27339607c7166d270d82a/f?aff_id=56556_18&im=25");
    }

});


 }

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList<String>>{
ArrayList<String> myarray;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    myarray=new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL url=new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String finalJson = buffer.toString();
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("offers");

        StringBuffer finalBufferData = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String contactid = finalObject.getString("app_name");
            //String custname = finalObject.getString("name");
            //String custemail = finalObject.getString("email");
            //String custgender = finalObject.getString("gender");
            //String mobileno = finalObject.getString("mobile");

            //finalBufferData.append(contactid + " - ");
            myarray.add(contactid);
        }
        return myarray;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if(reader !=null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
   // tvData.setText(result);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
    tvData.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: it is showing Null pointer exception in line myarray.add(contactid); Error says Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference. Please help resolving that.

Comment: oh sry i forget to make a new instance of the array . i edit it

Comment: anyway it seems that you dont know much knoweldge about basic coding i advise you to  study more about java programming before heading to android developing

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList object and update it with the result data. Return the Then pass it as an argument to the ArrayAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView tvData;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
    tvData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONTask().execute("http://a.nextput.com/offers/19/o/a0f252064bd27339607c7166d270d82a/f?aff_id=56556_18&im=25");
        }

    });


}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("offers");

            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String contactid = finalObject.getString("app_name");
                //String custname = finalObject.getString("name");
                //String custemail = finalObject.getString("email");
                //String custgender = finalObject.getString("gender");
                //String mobileno = finalObject.getString("mobile");

                //Add the data to the ArrayList
                data.append(contactid + " - ");
            }
            return data;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader !=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // tvData.setText(result);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        tvData.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```